# MySQL - LONGTEXT field causes hang in SELECT-WHERE statement

Tags: mysql, database, performance, longtext

I am having an issue due to `LONGTEXT` field. Everything works fine, but when a SELECT query is executed with any WHERE clause in it, the mysql goes to sleep and never returns. There are only 80k records and explicit WHERE comparison works fine. (Some records are over 1M, few are about 700K, but the rest are like only 60 to 100KB).

For example:

```
[HANGs]
SELECT * FROM item_info 
WHERE added_on > '2013-02-14 19:40:05' AND added_on < '2013-02-15 19:40:05'    
;which is like 2 rows only

[FINE]
SELECT * from item_info
WHERE item_id in (1, 10, 1000)
```

**Is this usual behavior?**

Here is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `item_info` (
  `item_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title_md5` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `original_document` longtext NOT NULL,
  `added_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `md5_Unique` (`title_md5`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=87781 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 CHECKSUM=1 DELAY_KEY_WRITE=1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

**Is there any solution? Or do I have to separate longtext field into a new table with a foreign key?**

Comment: this isn't have anything to do with `longtext` date comparisons can be costly.

Comment: @DanielA.White indeed but in this case there's only 88k records

Comment: Sounds like a locking issue. Where are you executing the query? From a language or from the SQL command line? I doubt it has anything to do with the LONGTEXT or date comparison.

Comment: executing/testing from both PHP as well as SQLYog....

Comment: its not just "datetime" field, there are other simple int fields, but the result is same... Only the Primary Key field works in Where query....

Answer (score 5):

You're using `MyISAM` tables. There's a restriction on them that is not present on `InnoDB`;

> MyISAM **always reads the complete row from the disk**, even if some fields are not queried in the SELECT.

The schema seems like you have an index on `item_id` but not on `added_on`.

Since you have no index on `added_on`, the query will generate a full table scan. A full table scan on a `MyISAM` table with long rows will need to read a *lot* of data from disk.

Adding an index on `added_on` will speed your query up quite a bit, since you'll only have to read the table rows actually needed.

Comment: its not just added_on, there are other simple fields and output is the same slow...

Comment: are you suggesting I should change it to `InnoDB`?

Comment: I thought `InnoDB` was the specialist for `acid transaction`; but for simply one way read, `MyISAM` was the best...

Comment: @RaheelHasan Because of the whole row read, if you have big rows but only use a few small fields, MyISAM isn't the best unless you index well. If you have a well indexed table for your load so that you avoid full table scans, it may outperform InnoDB but seldom by a huge margin. Fixing the whole row read was [closed as not a bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1900#c4097) and has afaik never been opened again.

Comment: @RaheelHasan Another solution besides adding indexes for your searches would be to (as suggested in the bug report linked above) put the LONGTEXT along with an ID in a separate table from the one where you need to do the searches.

Comment: Hi, actually Im using Solr for indexing....so indexing is not the concern here...

Comment: ok I converted it into InnoDB, but still no effect... still very very long to return just a few rows

Answer (score 0):

Sounds simple but if possible upgrade your version of MySQL, try increasing the memory limit and max execution time too.